# Set textarea to be exact width of content

Tags: html, css

So I'm working on a project and I want to have a textarea in the middle of the screen but with a placeholder that is left aligned. I need the textarea to be the exact width of the placeholder so that the text appears to actually be centered.

Is there a way to set the width of the textarea according to the number characters so that regardless of what font is loaded, the textarea width will adjust. Right now I'm just using vw to set the font-size and the textarea width but when loading the site on different computers with different system fonts, its not a completely reliable solution.

Here is the current working version of the project: https://beta.fontspark.app

Comment: And what about `em` units? If you know how many chars placeholder is.

Comment: @Smollet777 so would using em units adjust accordingly to which ever font the page is loaded with?

Comment: `em` unit is relative to the font size of the element.
`rem` - to the font size of **html** element

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5y6ohzcj/

Answer (score 0):

You can get the length of the placeholder and use div cols to set the with accordingly. You may need to subtract few cols when the placeholder doesnt fit. But it should do the work.

```js
$( function() {
    var taPlaceholder = $('textarea[placeholder]');
    taPlaceholder.attr('cols', taPlaceholder.attr('placeholder').length);
});
```

```css
textarea {
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea placeholder="This is random placeholder"></textarea>
```

Comment: You don't necessarily need jquery for this.

Comment: Yes. But he is using jquery anyway on his page. So why not?

Comment: Ok. I didn't check the page.